# How to remove last n number of numeric characters from a string in perl

Tags: regex, perl, character

I have a situation where I need to remove the last `n` numeric characters after a `/` character.

For eg:

```
/iwmout/sourcelayer/iwm_service/iwm_ear_layer/pomoeron.xml@@/main/lsr_int_vnl46a/61
```

After the last `/`, I need the number 61 stripped out of the line so that the output is,

```
/iwmout/sourcelayer/iwm_service/iwm_ear_layer/pomoeron.xml@@/main/lsr_int_vnl46a/
```

I tried using chop, but it removes only the last character, ie. 1, in the above example.

The last part, ie 61, above can be anything, like 221 or 2 or 100 anything. I need to strip out the last numeric characters after the `/`. Is it possible in Perl?

Answer (score 9):

A regex substitution for removing the last digits:

```
my $str = '/iwmout/sourcelayer/iwm_service/iwm_ear_layer/pomoeron.xml@@/main/lsr_int_vnl46a/61';
$str =~ s/\d+$//;
```

`\d+` matches a series of digits, and `$` matches the end of the line. They are replaced with the empty string.

Comment: @Pradeesh, if this answer worked for you, please mark it "Correct" by selecting the check mark

Answer (score 9):

@Tim's answer of `$str =~ s/\d+$//` is right on; however, if you wanted to strip the last *n* digit characters of a string but not necessarily *all* of the trailing digit characters you could do something like this:

```
my $s = "abc123456";
my $n = 3; # Just the last 3 chars.
$s =~ s/\d{$n}$//; # $s == "abc123"
```

Comment: Although this answers the question title, it does not answer what Pradeesh actually asked :)

Comment: Thank You very much for the replies. My problem there was that i am not sure what exactly the value of "n" is. It keeps changing as i am reading line by line from a file. Tim's Answer did the trick :).

Comment: @Tim: yes - that's why I started my answer with a nod to yours =)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Code to remove last n number of strings from a string.
// Import common lang jar
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello World";
        System.out.println(StringUtils.removeEnd(str, "ld"));
    }
}
```